# How to connect to MongoDB database from inside a Kubernetes Cluster running on the same host?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

So I have installed a MongoDB server on my local development machine inside a Docker container and can successfully read and write data from outside the container. However, I want to connect to this database from within my local kubernetes cluster running on the same machine.

I have created a K8 service  to do this:

```
 ---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports: 
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: mongo
subsets:
  - addresses:
    - ip: 172.17.0.2
    ports:
      - port: 27017
```

However when I run a shell from one of the pods in my cluster, I am unable to connect to establish a mongo shell connection.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am fairly new to K8. I have read the docs and I can't figure out why this isn't working...

Comment: What is the complete error message here?

Comment: So how exactly do you connect to your mongo db ? Please provide us with complete command. Are you able to connect to it from host machine using the same IP ?